# how to build simple qt application using yocto?

Tags: qt, yocto, bitbake, openembedded

I have **yocto** dev environment setup, in which I can bitbake and run a simple c++ application in the target. Now I want to try with simple Qt application. When I execute *bitbake-layers show-layers* it shows meta-qt5 in the list...

> meta-qt5
> /home/prc1cob/repo/out/salt/kawa/../../..//os/external/meta-qt5  7
> meta-oe
> /home/prc1cob/repo/out/salt/kawa/../../../build/yocto/meta-openembedded/meta-oe
> 6

With this, I assume qt5 is already present in my yocto build.
How to write .bb file to build a simple HelloWorld qt application as below...

```html
#include <QCoreApplication>
#include <QDebug>
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QCoreApplication a(argc, argv);
    
    qDebug() << "Hello World";

    return a.exec();
}
```

Thankyou!!

Answer (score 5):

Yocto provides a great class `qmake5` to compile QT projects based on QMake.

In order to use it create a `.pro` file for the project:

***qtexample.pro***

```
QT += core
SOURCES += qtexample.cpp
```

***qtexample.cpp***

```
#include <QCoreApplication>
#include <QDebug>
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QCoreApplication a(argc, argv);
    
    qDebug() << "Hello World";

    return a.exec();
}
```

Now, in your layer, you can add a simple recipe that compiles that project.

For example: `meta-custom/recipes-project/qtexample`

In `qtexample` folder create `files` folder and copy `qtexample.pro` and `qtexample.cpp` in it.

In `qtexample` folder directly create `qtexample_0.1.bb` recipe:

```
SUMMARY = "QT Example Recipe"
LICENSE = "CLOSED"

SRC_URI = "file://qtexample.pro \
           file://qtexample.cpp"

DEPENDS += "qtbase"
RDEPENDS_${PN} += "qtwayland"

S = "${WORKDIR}"

inherit qmake5
```

You can change the version ofcourse (0.1).

The layout should look like this:

```
meta-custom/
    ├── recipes-project/
        ├── qtexample_0.1.bb
        └── files/
            ├── qtexample.pro
            └── qtexample.cpp
```

Then, `bitbake qtexample` should work and create a `qtexample` binary that you can find in `${WORKDIR}`

Comment: @TALEL Thanks for the Great explanation. When I try to run bitbake got error as "ERROR: Nothing PROVIDES 'libnfc'", then removed libnfc in .bb file. now I am getting below errors in log.do_configure ..                                                          .../qtbase/5.12.3+gitAUTOINC+b527725766-r0/git/config.tests/x86_simd/main.cpp
> arm-poky-linux-gnueabi-g++: error: unrecognized command line option '-mrdrnd'
> Makefile:176: recipe for target 'main.o' failed
> make: *** [main.o] Error 1

Comment: Sorry, the libnfc and libmodbus were my mistake, so I removed them. I didn't understand the error, I think it is not related to the qt application. Please update your question and provide the error there in a more clear way.

Comment: I am not sure its related to Qt or not, but this error is thrown when qtbase is getting build : arm-poky-linux-gnueabi-g++: error: unrecognized command line option '-mrdrnd'  and from the log file the path for the error is shown as                                                                                                                tmp/work/armv7at2hf-neon-poky-linux-gnueabi/qtbase/5.12.3+gitAUTOINC+b527725766-r0/git/config.tests/x86_simd/main.cpp