# How to add and compile my QT application in Yocto image (which contains QT-5 layer.)?

Tags: qt, yocto

I am trying to add a qt widgets application/project to my yocto image and compile it through it. I know that I have to add a custom layer and make a recipe which has reference to the files of the qt application. I have also inherited qmake5 and inserted DEPENDS += "qtbase", but I am confused about which files to refer through SRC_UI in my recipe. The QT application file is a bare bone project called "hi" which contains no additional code and pops up a plain helloworld window. The project file contains following files:

```
    main.cpp 
    hi.pro 
    hi.pro.user
    mainwindow.cpp 
    mainwindow.h 
    ui_mainwindow.h
```

A reference recipe using above mentioned files would be really helpful.Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have an old response about `QT` recipes in `Yocto`.

Check: [how to build simple qt application using yocto?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68895012/how-to-build-simple-qt-application-using-yocto/68896403#68896403)

It contains a reference hello world recipe.

You just need to copy your files into recipes' folder and specify all files in `SRC_URI` or:

If your project is collected under one folder `hi`:

Place `hi` under: `qtexample/files` and specify it in the recipe:

```
SRC_URI = "file://hi"
S = "${WORKDIR}/hi"
```

**EDIT**:

Do not forget to mention the files to package:

```
FILES_${PN} = "/opt/*"
```

**EDIT2**:

If your recipe depends on a library or set of tools at run time, check what recipes are providing those libraries and add in your recipe:

```
RDEPENDS_${PN} += "recipe"
```

where `recipe` is what providing your runtime dependency.

Comment: I have followed the post. I have put all my qt files including the  files present in the build_release folder of QT in to a folder called hi and gave it's reference in recipe using

SRC_URI += "file://hi"

hi contains all the .cpp .h .ui .o and .pro type files.

Now  an error occurring: 

helloworld: Files/directories were installed but not shipped in any package:
 
 /opt/hi/bin/hi

i have added following in order to remove the error but not successful.

do_install_append () {
 install -d ${D}/opt/hi/bin
 install -m 0755 hi ${D}/opt/hi/bin
}

FILES_${PN} += "/opt/hi/bin/hi"

Comment: Try to specify all files `FILES_${PN} = "/opt/*"`

Comment: The image seems to be built. I am now going to test it on my raspberry pi. Can you kindly elaborate the reason behind the package issue ?

Comment: The `do_package` task needs to know what files to set for packaging, and it copies files that are installed in `${D}` to `${WORKDIR}/package` for `do_package_rpm/deb/ipk/tar` to create a package, if it finds files that are not specified in `FILES` then that error occurs, it is a QA check so you install only what it will be packaged.

Comment: I have added the `FILES` line to my response, if my response fixed your issue, please do not forget to accept it as correct answer .

Comment: Yes, the FILES line did resolve my issue of compilation and now I am getting a single binary file in my opt/hi/bin directory.  The question here now is that whether there should be additional files (such as .dll) alongside this binary file for it to execute when I call it because in my case there aren't any.

Comment: So, accept my answer and check my second EDIT.

Comment: So, I have tried to to execute the executable file obtained as a result of compilation through yocto recipe but it is not executing. Trying to execute the file through command line gives Error : cannot execute binary file : Exec format error." However the executable generated by QT creator using same project files works fine.